# node-waf configure clean build error

Tags: javascript, node.js, pcap

I'm trying to install `node_pcap` on my Windows machine but I keep getting the following error after running `npm install pcap`

```
node-waf configure clean build
node-waf is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

Both node and npm are up to date. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?